# R programming language mmedist The moment function must be defined. fdistrplus package

Tags: r

I'm trying to fit a distribution to some data using the function fdist from the package fdistrplus.

I've started learning R recently and got a hold of this package that I thought could do everything I needed.

When trying to use it to fit to a pareto distribution, I had to input my definitions of the pareto distribution like so:

```
ppareto = function(x,alpha,theta){
    (1-(theta/(x+theta))^alpha)*(x>=0)
}

dpareto = function(x,alpha,theta){
    (alpha*theta^alpha*(x+theta)^(-alpha-1))*(x>=0)
}

rpareto = function(n,alpha,theta){
l = array(as.numeric(NA),n)
ltmp = runif(n,0,1)
l = teta/ltmp^(1/alpha)-theta
return(l)
}
```

When calling

```
fitdist(data,"pareto",method = "mme")
```

It said it could not find the "dpareto" function. That is resolved by the code above.

Afterwards it said it needed an order parameter and a empirical moment parameter.
It's my understanding that the order parameter is the vector of orders that I want the routine to use as it's basis for the calculation.

So I tried:

```
fitdist(data,"pareto",method="mme",order=c(1,2))
```

As I saw in the examples of the package pdf.
Then it complained that:

Error in mmedist(data, distname, start = start, fix.arg = fix.arg, ...) : 
The moment function must be defined.

Okay, next step:

```
momentfunc = function(x,order){mean(x^order)}
```

To define the function.
Then I tried

```
fitdist(data,"pareto",method="mme",order=c(1,2),memp=momentfunc)
```

Error in mmedist(data, distname, start = start, fix.arg = fix.arg, ...) : 
The moment function must be defined.

Then I tried:

```
fitdist(data,"pareto",method="mme",order=c(1,2),memp="momentfunc")
```

Error in mmedist(data, distname, start = start, fix.arg = fix.arg, ...) : 
The moment function must be defined.

I've searched the web, found examples of the pareto dist and followed them step by step all to no avail...

I've searched stackoverflow and found nothing.

So here I am. If anyone could help me I would be much obliged.

Is it my dumb mistake? Is it a bug in the package?

I've tried this on Windows 7, R 3.1.0
and on MacOS, R 3.0.1 (where I get a warning that the package was built under R 3.0.2)

Thanks in advance

Comment: First of all, i'm assuming you meant the `fitdistrplus` package. But the `fitdist` function calls `mmedist` when you set `method="mme". I'm assuming you're trying to do the pareto function as an experiment, because this function exists in the `actuar` package already. But the piece that you are missing is the `mpareto` function. You passed the function that calculates the empirical moments, but the function is also looking for the theoretical moments. See `?mmedist` for more info and an example using the pareto distribution at the bottom.

Comment: Thank you for the package where the pareto is. Alas, I have the exact same problem with the weibull distribution and it has an "mweibull" defined...

Comment: That's odd, now I get
Error in mmedist(data, distname, start = start, fix.arg = fix.arg, ...) : 
  wrong dimension for the moment order to match.

Comment: I've run across this issue as well with fitdistrplus.

Answer (score 0):

you have to install and load the 'actuar' package

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already knew that back in 2014 when in a comment they said that. I was having the same type of issue with the weibull distribution.
Since then I've moved on and never needed R again.